# Multiple ionic views fails to render

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, ionic-view, angularjs-view

How do I have multiple ionic views? - I've tried a variety of things to get it to work, but all failed...

Here are the relevant parts of my Angular Ionic app:

#### View

```html
<body ng-app="ionic_appname">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    <ion-nav-view name="errorsView" title="Errors"></ion-nav-view>
```

#### Routing

```js
.config(
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('errors', {
                views: {
                    errorsView: {
                        templateUrl: 'main/templates/errors.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'main/templates/home.html',
            })
    }
```

#### main/templates/errors.html

```html
<h3>Errors ahoy</h3>
```

#### main/templates/home.html

```html
<h3>Tadaima</h3>
```

---

However the rendered output is just:

```
<body ng-app="ionic_appname" class="grade-a platform-browser platform-win32 platform-ready">
    <ion-nav-view class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios" nav-view-direction="none" nav-swipe="">
        <ion-view view-title="Home" class="pane" nav-view="active" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);">
            <h3>Tadaima</h3>
        </ion-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
    <ion-nav-view name="errorsView" title="Errors" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios"></ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "multiple views"? Multiple view all simultaneously visible?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Maybe states are the wrong thing, and I should be using `ng-include` or even a custom `directive` instead...

Answer (score 0):

Have you already seen this Plunker?

http://plnkr.co/edit/UkXhXK?p=preview

It uses a "nested-views" approach which probably you could adopt in your project.
For example:

```
  .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
      views:{
        'homePage': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeController'
        },
        'errorPage': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/errors.html',
          controller: 'ErrorController'
        }
      },
      onEnter: function(){
        console.log("enter home");
      }
  })
```

Comment: Yes, I know the subview approach, but that would require namespacing everything, because all emit to the error state.